# rosrun Couldn't find executable named node_name.py

Tags: ros

I am using ROS Noetic on Windows 10, and I created a python node using this directory structure

```
\catkin_ws\src\package_name\scripts>
```

and my node's Python files are inside `scripts` folder.
I can run the nodes from within the `scripts` folder using

```
python node_name.py
```

and can run the node within `scripts` folder using

```
rosrun package_name node_name.py
```

but when I try to run the node from the `\catkin_ws\` folder using

```
 rosrun package_name node_name.py
```

I get this error

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named node_name.py
```

I have already run

```
\ros\noetic\x64\setup.bat     
\devel\setup.bat
```

Why are my nodes are not recognizable by `rosrun` outside the `scripts` folder and how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided enough information, but my first guess is that you did not make your script executable on the system. rosrun looks for executables available in each packages.

There's an FAQ in the [Python Documentation about Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable)

In ROS 2 we typically don't just write scripts and expect them to run, but leverage official python entry points in the setup.py which the python installer will correctly setup for execution on Windows.

Comment: So I should convert the python.py files to executables .exe files, right?

Comment: You could do that, but in general it's likely not worth it. You could keep explicitly invoking them with python3 explicitly. rosrun is just a convenience method. It doesn't do anything beyond finding the executable elsewhere on the path.

Comment: What I've seen on Windows (but I don't exactly recommend), is that you can have `node_name.bat`, which does something like `python3 relative\path\to\node_name.py`, then you could run `ros2 run pkg_name node_name.bat`, but of course that wouldn't work on Linux. Also you'd need to deal with executing it in different working directories, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10712935 if you want to handle that.

But @Tully's recommendation of running it with python directly or using the https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/entry-points/#use-for-scripts is the portable way to go.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the ".py" after you build your workspace

Comment: Please provide a helpful explanation with your answers here so that others in the future can understand how your suggestion might apply to their similar problems.